# small data set and number of independent variables is larger than number of observations . What to do ? Should I apply Lasso?

Tags: multiple-regression, model-selection, lasso

In my data set I have only 6 observations & independent variables are 9.

Can I use Lasso regression or multiple regression in this situation?
when independent variables are  > observations?

Data :

```
  y      x1      x2      x3     x4    x5    x6     x7   x8      x9
6142.8  90.25   164.19  15     0.91  0.88   2.99  0.5   7.255   15
8174.2  126.9   64.56   7.5    0.92  0.87   2.98  0.5   7.255   3.5
6967.8  111.98  137.72  30     0.83  0.89   3     0.5   7.905   30
6419.3  92.23   55.23   7.5    0.86  0.92   2.99  0.5   7.905   15
6093.4  98.63   184.15  30     0.88  0.87   3     0.5   7.255   30  
6460.9  108.35  129.5   7.5    0.89  0.88   2.99  0.5   7.255   3.5
```

I would really appreciate if you could suggest some methods/techniques or strategies to solve this problems.

Comment: @subhashc.davar , I want to predict y, and check that which independent variables are comes in the final model, where we get correct prediction for y.

Comment: @subhashc.davar, dependent variable is (y=crop_yield), x1 is area per crop in hectare, x2 is rainfall(mm),  x3 is depth of water level, x4 is soil content (N), x5 is soil content (P) , x6 is soil content (K) , x7 is soil content (Ec) , x8 is soil content (PH), x9 is central ground water level.  this data is not scale , all data is in correct value, without normalize .

Comment: @subhashc.davar, so I want to create a model for yield for single single crops for single single districts.

Comment: It means you have a number of Districts and a number of crops. small dataset you have qouted is for  a particular distt. and for a particular crop ?

Comment: @subhashc.davar, yes, this data for Latur district for paddy crop . (y = paddy yield kg/hectare). and this 6 observation is talukas in Latur district, there have 6 talukas yield, so I want to predict the yield , if rainfall comes ...mm, soil content is ... this, then paddy yield will comes in this __kg. likewise

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55948/discussion-between-kiran-prajapati-and-subhash-c-davar).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55949/discussion-between-kiran-prajapati-and-subhash-c-davar).